# Drupal 7 errors after upgrading from 7.12 to 7.14

Tags: entities

I just updated my drupal version from 7.12 to 7.14 and now I get these errors when trying to update/edit a content type:

```
Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array in _form_set_class() (line 4134 of /var/www/vhosts/xxx/public_html/includes/form.inc).

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in theme_radios() (line 2809 of /var/www/vhosts/xxx/public_html/includes/form.inc).

An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.
```

Please note that this is happening when I edit the node not the actual content type definition. But only for this one particular content type. All the other work fine still.

If it's at all helpful here are the fields for that content type:

```
Title - title - Node module element     

Photo - field_photo_image - Image - Image

Vote - field_photo_vote - Fivestar Rating - Stars (rated while viewing)

Domain access - domain - Domain Access settings.        

Description - field_photo_description - Long text - Text area (multiple rows)

Author - field_photo_author Text - Text field

Admin selected - field_photo_winner - Boolean - Single on/off checkbox
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and found the solution here: http://drupal.org/node/1427430

Do you happen to also have the opengraph_meta module installed?
If so just edit this file:

```
sites/[your-site]/modules/opengraph_meta/opengraph_meta.module
```

search for this line:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => 'opengraph-thumbs-wrapper clearfix'),
```

and change it to look like this one:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => array('opengraph-thumbs-wrapper','clearfix')),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that something has gone wrong with the update version. Are you sure you've followed step by step the upgrade guide ?

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/UPGRADE.txt/7

Comment: I didn't out the site into maintainance mode.. everything else I did correctly. What do I do now to fix this.... The databse has been updated. Do I need to roll back to the previous version and import a db backup? then try this again?

Comment: Honestly I'm not very sure., but I do not see another solution.. let's wait a while, maybe someone comes up with another idea.

Comment: Hi @Voislav Sauca I did a rebuild then imported the site again with backup and migrate.. problem was still there. I then deleted the Content Type and recreated it.. problem was still there. I then started to remove one field at a time and discovered once I removed the `image` field it worked and errors were gone. I tried the `file` field instead and the errors came back. Do you know why this is happening?